# Doubts on finding complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

**So far I think I understand the basic of finding algorithm complexity:**

- Basics operations like read,write,assignments and allocations have constant complexity O(k) that can be simplified as O(1).

**For loops you have to think of the worst case, so for what value n the loop will take the longest time:**

- The complexity is O(n) if there are constant increments, for example if you have a variable i that            starts from 0 and you increase it or decrease it by one at each loop iteration until you reach n.
- The complexity  is O(logn) if you have a variable and you increase it or decrease it by multiples.
- The complexity is O(n^2) if there are nested loops.
- If in a function there are multiple loops, the complexity of the function will be the loop with the worst complexity.
- In case the value n doesn't change, and you always have to iterate n times, you use the Θ notation  because there isn't a worst case or best case scenario.

Please correct me if anything I said so far is wrong.

**For recursive functions the complexity depends on how many recursive calls there will be in the worst case scenario, you have to find a recurrence relation and solve it with one of the 3 methods:**

This is where  the problems begin for me:

**Example**

Let's say I have a binary tree with this structure: pointer to left and right child and value of depth of the node.

There is a function that initially takes the root and wants to perform an operation on each left child of nodes that have odd depths. To solve this with recursion, I'll have to check if node has odd depth, if it has a left child,if yes perform the operation on left child and then make the recursive call to the next node. In this case I think the complexity should be O(n), where n is the number of odd nodes and the worst case is that all odd nodes have a left child.

But what's the recurrence relation in a function like this?

Comment: do you have a worst case idea of how deep your tree could be ?

Comment: If the tree is balanced, then _O(log n)_, otherwise _O(n)_.

Comment: @Andreas is n the total number of nodes or is it the total number of odd nodes?